# Android alarm driver

Tags: android, real-time, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I am new to android, I want to know the implementation of alarm.c
particularly why android alarm needs the RTC support. Alarm works for
me only when i enable RTC support. can you please explain in brief way
whats the importance of RTC in alarm

Thanks
Regards
Shabbir

Answer (score 1):

**Improtance of RTC.**

It is  ***REAL TIME CLOCK*** .
you are working on application layer .Its not important for you how its work.

Real-Time Clock (RTC) Counts Seconds, Minutes, Hours, Date of the Month, Month, 
     Day of the Week, and Year with Leap-Year
That you call it by programing.

it is IC (hardware part).
if you want to know more about it please go through link;

[RTC IC DataSHEET](http://datasheets.maxim-ic.com/en/ds/DS1305.pdf)

Comment: @shabbir Did you get your answer>?